# CALayer opacity animation works but bounds animation doesn't

Tags: ios, ruby, cocoa-touch, core-animation, rubymotion

I'm trying to animate the bounds of a CALayer and it's not working. Here's the code:

```
class CircleView < UIIVew

  def initWithFrame(frame)
    super

    # determine the dimensions
    radius = (bounds.size.width < bounds.size.height ? bounds.size.width : bounds.size.height) / 2

    # create the circle layer
    @circle = CAShapeLayer.layer
    @circle.bounds = bounds
    @circle.path = UIBezierPath.bezierPathWithRoundedRect(bounds, cornerRadius: radius).CGPath

    @circle.fillColor = UIColor.blueColor.CGColor

    # add the circle to the view
    self.layer.addSublayer(@circle)

    shrink

    self
  end

  private

  # Applies the shrink animation to the provided circle layer.
  def shrink

    # determine the bounds
    old_bounds = @circle.bounds
    new_bounds = CGRectMake(old_bounds.size.width / 2, old_bounds.size.height / 2, 0, 0)

    # animate the shrinking
    animation = CABasicAnimation.animationWithKeyPath("bounds")
    animation.fromValue = NSValue.valueWithCGRect(old_bounds)
    animation.toValue = NSValue.valueWithCGRect(new_bounds)
    animation.duration = 3.0
    @circle.addAnimation(animation, forKey:"bounds")

    # set the bounds so the animation doesn't bounce back when it's complete
    @circle.bounds = new_bounds
  end

  # Applies the shrink animation to the provided circle layer.
  def disappear

    # animate the shirnk
    animation = CABasicAnimation.animationWithKeyPath("opacity")
    animation.fromValue = NSNumber.numberWithFloat(1.0)
    animation.toValue = NSNumber.numberWithFloat(0.0)
    animation.duration = 3.0
    @circle.addAnimation(animation, forKey:"opacity")

    # set the value so the animation doesn't bound back when it's completed
    @circle.opacity = 0.0
  end
end
```

If I call disappear from the `initWithFrame` method, the animation works fine. However, calling shrink does nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because you are using a `CAShapeLayer`. The `path` is independent of the `bounds`, so you have to animate it separately.

I could reproduce your problem with a version of your code roughly translated to Objective C. When I changed the `shrink`method to this, it worked:

```
-(void)shrink
{
  CGRect old_bounds = self.circle.bounds;
  CGRect new_bounds = CGRectMake(old_bounds.size.width / 2, old_bounds.size.height / 2, 0, 0);

  // bounds
  CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath: @"bounds"];
  animation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGRect: old_bounds];
  animation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGRect: new_bounds];
  animation.duration = 3.0;
  [self.circle addAnimation: animation forKey: @"bounds"];

  // path
  CGPathRef old_path = self.circle.path;
  CGPathRef new_path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:new_bounds cornerRadius:0].CGPath;

  CABasicAnimation *pathAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath: @"path"];
  pathAnimation.fromValue = (__bridge id)(old_path);
  pathAnimation.toValue = (__bridge id)(new_path);
  pathAnimation.duration = 3.0;
  [self.circle addAnimation: pathAnimation forKey: @"path"];

  //set the value so the animation doesn't bound back when it's completed
  self.circle.bounds = new_bounds;
  self.circle.path = new_path;
}
```

Technically, you might not even have to animate the bounds. If you set a distinct `backgroundColor` on your `circle` layer, you can experiment a little and more easily see how `bounds`and `path` can be set and animated more or less independently (for example, in your original code you could see that the bounds are in fact animated but the path stays the same).

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thanks for the help! I was able to leave the bounds animation out.

Answer (score -2):

Not knowing Ruby, I would suggest adjusting the frame rather than the bounds.  The bounds are in the CALayers own coordinate system, and have no bearing on how the layer itself is displayed in the parent.

Comment: Apple Docs: frame:
This property is not animatable. You can achieve the same results by animating the bounds and position properties.
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/AnimatableProperties/AnimatableProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH11-SW1

Comment: Apologies, you're currently using the bounds to set the origin, of the layer in respect to its parent.  This will only affect its content not the layer itself - whereas a frame does what you want.  The apple docs you link to indicate that the position is animatable.  The position is relative to the anchorPoint which is by default, the center of the bounds.  To animate the size of the layer, use the bounds.  [apple dev link with more info](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#qa/qa1620/_index.html)